# I have created a C# program which uses Google Translate API .. But I am not able to fetch the results which are not in english language

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to get the result from Google translate API using C# program. My code works fine for translation which are in english but for other language it returns something like ?????? ??? ??? I have tried almost all type of UNICODE conversion.

```
string url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=APIKEY";    
    url += "&source=" + "en"; /// English as Source Language
                url += "&target=" + "Hi"; /// Hindi as Target Language
                url += "&q=" + "Good Morning Vivek"; /// Translation String

                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                string json = client.DownloadString(url);
                json = client.DownloadString(url);
                Console.WriteLine("Json : " + json);
```

Below is the JSON string output

```
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "translatedText": "??? ???????? ?????"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: did you checked that the problem is in what's being returned and not with jut printing to console?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because either it's a typo (when you print it it's showing a question marks, but c# understand it just fine), or you need to consult with Google's developer network to get support with their API.

Comment: let me give you one example .. In my above code when I am passing the string as "I am Vivek Mehta" and target language as 'Japanese' .. the output I am getting is "ç§ã¯Vivek Mehtaã§ã™"  which does not make sense ... when I am printing the jason output to see what is being fetched from API it is like ??? ????? ????? .... So, can you please tell me how to read this using c# ... I am getting the correct translation for other languages which are using English alphabets.